# Android BufferedReader missing some letter

Tags: android

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
System.out.print("Received string: '");

while (!in.ready()) {

}

int result = in.read();
// String result1=in.readLine();
char[] buf = new char[50];

in.read(buf);

String b = new String(buf);
text.setText(b);
```

I sent the word `"hello world"` from the server but what I got back is `"ello world"` from the above code . It's missing the first letter h. I used `read` instead of `readLine` because `readLine` doesn't work, it crashed.

Another issue,  hello world is displayed in 2 lines instead of one. layout for textview is wrap_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is consuming the first character:

```
int result=in.read();
```

Hence when you do this, buf will not contain it:

```
in.read(buf);
```

You can use the mark() and reset() functions on the buffered reader if you need to go back to the beginning. Or otherwise just comment out that line.

Comment: Ok, it's fixed. I have another issue  hello world is displayed in 2 lines instead of one. layout for textview is wrap_content.

Comment: Try android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
System.out.print("Received string: '");
String inputLine;
String b = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
 b = inputLine;
 System.out.println(b);
 //or do whatever you want with b
}
```

With this you will also be able to read multiple lines (in case you reveived more than one)...

> I used read instead of readLine because readLine doesn't work, it
>   crashed.

It should not crash...i suggest you should fix this first